# Изображение внутри дива без нижнего горизонтального зазора

Tags: html5, css3

Как правильно оформить стиль, чтобы изображение `img` внутри `div` не имело нижнего горизонтального 'зазора'? В примере кода пытаюсь убрать горизонтальный зазор между изображениями. Пробовал комбинацию min/max -height, - не получилось. Как делают адаптивное расположение фоток без зазоров?

---

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background: #E8DDCF;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
 width:100%; 
    background: #F3E7D8;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF; 
}


.f {
    width: 98.4%;
 height: 9%;
    border: 1px solid #F3E7D8;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.f:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}


.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu"> </div> 

<div id='content'>
<div id='fotos'>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="01"><div class="bottomleft">q</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="02"><div class="bottomleft">w</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="03"><div class="bottomleft">e</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="04"><div class="bottomleft">r</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="05"><div class="bottomleft">t</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="06"><div class="bottomleft">y</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="07"><div class="bottomleft">u</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="08"><div class="bottomleft">i</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="09"><div class="bottomleft">o</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="10"><div class="bottomleft">p</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `img{display: block; }`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background: #E8DDCF;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
 width:100%; 
    background: #F3E7D8;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF; 
}


.f {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #F3E7D8;    
    margin: 0 auto;
  
  display: block;
}


.f:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}


.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu"> </div> 

<div id='content'>
<div id='fotos'>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="01"><div class="bottomleft">q</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="02"><div class="bottomleft">w</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="03"><div class="bottomleft">e</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="04"><div class="bottomleft">r</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="05"><div class="bottomleft">t</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="06"><div class="bottomleft">y</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="07"><div class="bottomleft">u</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="08"><div class="bottomleft">i</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="09"><div class="bottomleft">o</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://www.syntaxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/intro-to-css3-logo-300.png" alt="10"><div class="bottomleft">p</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Адаптивные изображения.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

И чтобы не было проблем с отступами:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*p.s: `img { dispaly: inline-block; }` - по-умолчанию*

Comment: Elena Semenchenko, c display: block; пока не получилось ... пробую

Comment: Елена, а разве img не блочный элемент по умолчанию?

Comment: @Alex, подправила, может быть так заработает.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, понял

Comment: Elena Semenchenko, работает, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Еще как вариант
добавить `line-height: 0` для `.container`

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background: #E8DDCF;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
 width:100%; 
    background: #F3E7D8;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF; 
}


.f {
    width: 98.4%;
 height: 9%;
    border: 1px solid #F3E7D8;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.f:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0;
}


.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: blue;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"> </div> 

<div id='content'>
<div id='fotos'>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="01"><div class="bottomleft">q</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="02"><div class="bottomleft">w</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="03"><div class="bottomleft">e</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="04"><div class="bottomleft">r</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="05"><div class="bottomleft">t</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="06"><div class="bottomleft">y</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="07"><div class="bottomleft">u</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="08"><div class="bottomleft">i</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="09"><div class="bottomleft">o</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="http://party-boom.ru/catalog_photo/6018580s.png" alt="10"><div class="bottomleft">p</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: soledar10, работает, - очень хороший вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

```
img{width:100%;height:auto}
```